Get Earlies & Latest Date per customer - DAX
I have two tables connected together by date. I want to create a calculation which will calculate the earlies and the latest date per customer.

First Contact Column = CALCULATE ( MIN(DimDate[Date]), ALLEXCEPT(FctTrc, FctTrc[Customer]) )

I have create a calculation but it giving me the earliest date of the date table.
Any help?

First Contact Column = CALCULATE(  MIN(FctTrc[Date]), REMOVEFILTERS(), VALUES(FctTrc[Customer]))

should be all you need.

Why i can not use the date column from the dimension table?

Why do you need to? I'll update the formula now to be more flexible.
